# Why are some of the mysql tables lost when restoring from a dump in a docker container?

Tags: docker

When restoring a database from a dump, some tables were lost. What could be the mistake?
The content of the docker-compose orchestration file looks like this:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db_mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.22
    container_name: db_mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
     - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
     - ./tz2.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/tz2.sql
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
     - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
     - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    restart: always
    depends_on:
     - db_mysql
    ports:
     - "8080:80"
    volumes:
     - /sessions
     - ~/docker/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php
     - /custom/phpmyadmin/theme/:/www/themes/theme/
```

Comment: Is the dump in the SQL file? Are the tables you miss included there? How did you do the backup?

Comment: The dump was done by another programmer. The database from a dump not in Docker was restored correctly.